# "That would be John" vs. "That will be John"

Tags: modal-verbs

When I hear someone knocking on the door, and I think that John is behind the door. should I say "That would be John" or "That will be John"?

Comment: What you say depends on what you want what you say to mean. This question is rather similar to [Why is "that would be me" more certain than "that is me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165864) and the other questions linked there: using *would* is a hedge.

Comment: I would say "that will be John" because the person you expect to be John is currently at the door: "that would be John" is used in less immediate situations, usually referring to the past. For instance someone says "I spoke to a tall guy with dark hair yesterday, he dealt with my request" and you respond "That would be (or would have been) John, I'll see if he's available"

Comment: Similar: [When should I use “Would”, “Would have”, “Will”, and “Will have”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657). It would be good to edit the question to show some evidence of research.

Comment: "That will be John" means you were expecting him and there he is, as planned.  "That would be John" means you're using a bit of deduction.

Answer (score 2):

Either can be used correctly.

> That would be John.

Is basically saying "I assume that that is John" (= an assumption in the present)

> That will be John.

Is basically saying "The person who knocked will soon be revealed to be John" (= a certainty in the near future)

Notice the difference about how certain the speaker is. "would" communicates that the speaker *guesses* that it is John, "will" communicates that the speaker is *sure* that it must be John.
The speaker can of course still be **wrong**, but at least he isn't doubting himself at the time of making the statement.